# Unable to create Controller or View in Asp.net mvc (C# Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am working on asp.net mvc project (Programming language: C#) in Visual studio 2019(version: 16.2.2). While creating Controller or view, I am getting this error.[image]

Error says "**There was an error running the selected code generator: the value -1 is outside the acceptable range of [0, 2147483647]. Parameter name value**". I have already tried to find the solution but so far I am not able to fix it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Before you try and create the controller or view, does the project compile?

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the **ComponentModelCache**, the cache will rebuild next time VS is launched.

- Close Visual Studio Delete everything in this folder
- C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
- Restart Visual Studio

14.0 is for visual studio 2015. This will work for other versions also.

Comment: Build is successful. I have already cleared ComponentModelCache but still I am getting same error.